# How to remove html special chars?

Tags: php, html-encode

I am creating a RSS feed file for my application in which I want to remove HTML tags, which is done by `strip_tags`. But `strip_tags` is not removing HTML special code chars:

```
&nbsp; &amp; &copy;
```

etc.

Please tell me any function which I can use to remove these special code chars from my string.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Either decode them using `html_entity_decode` or remove them using `preg_replace`:

```
$Content = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$Content);
```

(From [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/7046.htm))

EDIT: Alternative according to Jacco's comment

> might be nice to replace the '+' with
>   {2,8} or something. This will limit
>   the chance of replacing entire
>   sentences when an unencoded '&' is
>   present.

```
$Content = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$Content);
```

Comment: might be nice to replace the  '+' with '{2,8]  or something. This will limit the chance of replacing entire sentences when an unencoded  '&' is present.

Comment: Thanks, added your comment and an alternative version to the answer.

Comment: I made a typo: it should be {2,8} sorry about that

Comment: but why would one want to remove those characters?

Comment: Those character-entities are not valid in RSS/Atom/XML. so you can do 2 thing: remove them, or replace them with their number-equivalent.

Comment: A possible case for having to remove them is when stripping HTML for sending it as an alternate, plain-text body along in an email.

Comment: What about &hellip; & + hellip is that caught by the above regular expression?

Comment: This is really clean and useful suggestions to remove special characters for title tag values which shows ? marks or decoded entities in the browser tab, which is not good.

Answer (score 21):

Use [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert HTML entities.

You'll need to set charset to make it work correctly.

Comment: this is more correctly because when we just replace &nbsp; with empty string we get incorrect result - all non breakable spaces are collapsed

Comment: This! All you need is run the `html_entity_decode` on the string and then use `strip_tags` and lastly use `filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the good answers above, PHP also has a built-in filter function that is quite useful: `filter_var`.

To remove HTML characters, use:

`$cleanString = filter_var($dirtyString, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

**More info:**

1. [function.filter-var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)
2. [filter_sanitize_string](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_string.asp)

Comment: I know the thread is a little old, but I am looking to solve the same problem... Unfortunately filter_var requires 5.2 or newer...Otherwise this would be the answer (at least to my specific problem).  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You may want take a look at htmlentities() and html_entity_decode() [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to *convert* the HTML special characters and not just remove them as well as strip things down and prepare for plain text this was the solution that worked for me...

```
function htmlToPlainText($str){
    $str = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $str);
    $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_COMPAT , 'UTF-8');
    $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
    $str = html_entity_decode($str);
    $str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
    $str = strip_tags($str);

    return $str;
}

$string = '<p>this is (&nbsp;) a test</p>
<div>Yes this is! &amp; does it get "processed"? </div>'

htmlToPlainText($string);
// "this is ( ) a test. Yes this is! & does it get processed?"`
```

html_entity_decode w/ ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1 converts things like `&#39;`
htmlspecialchars_decode converts things like `&amp;` 
html_entity_decode converts things like `'&lt;`
and strip_tags removes any HTML tags left over.

**EDIT** - Added str_replace(' ', ' ', $str); and several other html_entity_decode() as continued testing has shown a need for them.

Comment: also add 
str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $str);

so that &nbsp; don't get to covert in some type of special char as it was happening in my case .

Answer (score 3):

This might work well to remove special characters.

```
$modifiedString = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]/", "", $content);
```

Answer (score 2):

A plain vanilla strings way to do it without engaging the preg regex engine:

```
function remEntities($str) {
  if(substr_count($str, '&') && substr_count($str, ';')) {
    // Find amper
    $amp_pos = strpos($str, '&');
    //Find the ;
    $semi_pos = strpos($str, ';');
    // Only if the ; is after the &
    if($semi_pos > $amp_pos) {
      //is a HTML entity, try to remove
      $tmp = substr($str, 0, $amp_pos);
      $tmp = $tmp. substr($str, $semi_pos + 1, strlen($str));
      $str = $tmp;
      //Has another entity in it?
      if(substr_count($str, '&') && substr_count($str, ';'))
        $str = remEntities($tmp);
    }
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I have done was to use: `html_entity_decode`, then use `strip_tags` to removed them.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php
$str = "\x8F!!!";

// Outputs an empty string
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

// Outputs "!!!"
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
?>
```

Comment: make some notes "why your code works"? So it would be clear to others.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you really want is:

```
function xmlEntities($string) {
    $translationTable = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES);

    foreach ($translationTable as $char => $entity) {
        $from[] = $entity;
        $to[] = '&#'.ord($char).';';
    }
    return str_replace($from, $to, $string);
}
```

It replaces the named-entities with their number-equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function strip_only($str, $tags, $stripContent = false) {
    $content = '';
    if(!is_array($tags)) {
        $tags = (strpos($str, '>') !== false
                 ? explode('>', str_replace('<', '', $tags))
                 : array($tags));
        if(end($tags) == '') array_pop($tags);
    }
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        if ($stripContent)
             $content = '(.+</'.$tag.'[^>]*>|)';
         $str = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>'.$content.'#is', '', $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

$str = '<font color="red">red</font> text';
$tags = 'font';
$a = strip_only($str, $tags); // red text
$b = strip_only($str, $tags, true); // text
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function I used to perform the task, joining the upgrade made by schnaader is:

```
    mysql_real_escape_string(
        preg_replace_callback("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i", function($m) { 
            return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); 
        }, strip_tags($row['cuerpo'])))
```

This function removes every html tag and html symbol, converted in UTF-8 ready to save in MySQL

Comment: creating an rss feed, not saving to sql

Answer (score 0):

You can try `htmlspecialchars_decode($string)`. It works for me.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars_decode.asp

Comment: Downvoted for linking to w3chools instead of the official documentation:
http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode

That said, this does not solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in WordPress and are like me and simply need to check for an empty field (and there are a copious amount of random html entities in what seems like a blank string) then take a look at:

```
sanitize_title_with_dashes( string $title, string $raw_title = '', string $context = 'display' )
```

[Link to wordpress function page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/)

For people not working on WordPress, I found this function REALLY useful to create my own sanitizer, take a look at the full code and it's really in depth!

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = "äáčé";

$convert = Array(
        'ä'=>'a',
        'Ä'=>'A',
        'á'=>'a',
        'Á'=>'A',
        'à'=>'a',
        'À'=>'A',
        'ã'=>'a',
        'Ã'=>'A',
        'â'=>'a',
        'Â'=>'A',
        'č'=>'c',
        'Č'=>'C',
        'ć'=>'c',
        'Ć'=>'C',
        'ď'=>'d',
        'Ď'=>'D',
        'ě'=>'e',
        'Ě'=>'E',
        'é'=>'e',
        'É'=>'E',
        'ë'=>'e',
    );

$string = strtr($string , $convert );

echo $string; //aace
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs issue

Answer (score -1):

#### What If By "Remove HTML Special Chars" You Meant "Replace Appropriately"?

After all, just look at your example...

```
&nbsp; &amp; &copy;
```

If you're stripping this for an RSS feed, shouldn't you want the equivalents?

```
" ", &, ©
```

Or maybe you don't *exactly want the equivalents.*  Maybe you'd want to have `&nbsp;` just be ignored (to prevent too much space), but then have `&copy;` actually get replaced.  Let's work out a solution that solves anyone's version of this problem...

#### How to *SELECTIVELY-REPLACE* HTML Special Chars

The logic is simple: `preg_match_all('/(&#[0-9]+;)/'` grabs all of the matches, and then we simply build a list of matchables and replaceables, such as `str_replace([searchlist], [replacelist], $term)`.  Before we do this, we also need to convert named entities to their numeric counterparts, i.e., `"&nbsp;"` is unacceptable, but `"&#00A0;"` is fine.  (Thanks to [it-alien's solution to this part of the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39898858/2430549))

#### Working Demo

In this demo, I replace `&#123;` with `"HTML Entity #123"`.  Of course, you can fine-tune this to any kind of find-replace you want for your case.

Why did I make this?  I use it with *generating Rich Text Format from UTF8-character-encoded HTML.*

See full working demo:

[**Full Online Working Demo**](https://ideone.com/PPAo1g)

```
    function FixUTF8($args) {
        $output = $args['input'];
        
        $output = convertNamedHTMLEntitiesToNumeric(['input'=>$output]);
        
        preg_match_all('/(&#[0-9]+;)/', $output, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $full_matches = $matches[0];
        
        $found = [];
        $search = [];
        $replace = [];
        
        for($i = 0; $i < count($full_matches); $i++) {
            $match = $full_matches[$i];
            $word = $match[0];
            if(!$found[$word]) {
                $found[$word] = TRUE;
                $search[] = $word;
                $replacement = str_replace(['&#', ';'], ['HTML Entity #', ''], $word);
                $replace[] = $replacement;
            }
        }

        $new_output = str_replace($search, $replace, $output);
        
        return $new_output;
    }
    
    function convertNamedHTMLEntitiesToNumeric($args) {
        $input = $args['input'];
        return preg_replace_callback("/(&[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;)/",function($m){
            $c = html_entity_decode($m[0],ENT_HTML5,"UTF-8");
            # return htmlentities($c,ENT_XML1,"UTF-8"); -- see update below
            
            $convmap = array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
            return mb_encode_numericentity($c, $convmap, 'UTF-8');
        }, $input);
    }

print(FixUTF8(['input'=>"Oggi &egrave; un bel&nbsp;giorno"]));
```

Input:

> `"Oggi &egrave; un bel&nbsp;giorno"`

Output:

> `Oggi HTML Entity #232 un belHTML Entity #160giorno`