# Symfony2 Crawler - Use UTF-8 with XPATH

Tags: php, symfony, xpath, encoding, web-crawler

I am using Symfony2 Crawler - Bundle for using XPath.
Everything works fine, except the encoding.

I would like to use UTF-8 encoding and the Crawler is somehow not using it. I noticed that because th `&nbsp;` are converted to `Â&nbsp;`, which is a known issue: [UTF-8 Encoding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597105/why-cant-i-get-rid-of-this-nbsp)

My question is: How could I force the Symfony Crawler to use UTF-8 Encoding?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$dom_input = new \DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$dom_input->encoding = "UTF-8";
$dom_input->formatOutput = true;

$dom_input->loadHTMLFile($myFile);

$crawler = new Crawler($dom_input); 
$paragraphs = $crawler->filterXPath('descendant-or-self::p');
```

And now, when I am doing

```
foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    var_dump($paragraph->nodeValue);
}
```

As soon as I have a `&nbsp;` in my paragraph, I am getting `Â&nbsp;`.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I've answered that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802344/472495).

Comment: I'ma fraid this is not working for me. I found a workaround, using `crawler->addHtmlContent(utf8_decode($dom_input->saveXML()));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @halfer, I found a workaround:

Instead of using

```
$crawler = new Crawler($dom_input);
```

I used:

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent(utf8_decode($dom_input->saveXML()));
```

Comment: I guess that means that `$dom_input->saveXML()` isn't emitting UTF-8 then, which is a bit odd, considering how you've set it up! Still, if you are confident the input format won't change, your workaround should be okay.