# How to remove encoded HTML tags from a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, htmlspecialchars

A web service that I am accessing send the following response...

```
&lt;strong&gt;result&lt;/strong&gt;
```

How can I strip the string of these encoded tags?

Comment: maybe convert to HTML and then strip_tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars-in-php

Comment: I tried using `htmlspecialchars` and `html_entity_decode` in conjunction. I missed the `strip_tags`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '&lt;strong&gt;result&lt;/strong&gt;';
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str));
```