# Remove HTML codes from string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to remove all HTML codes like `&quot; &euro; &aacute; ...` from a string using REGEX.

String: `"This is a string &quot; &euro; &aacute; &amp;"`

Output Required: `This is a string`

Comment: [How to remove html special chars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars).

Comment: I am new to regex and want to create something which will index words from a webpage.

Comment: Since you just want to get words, why not instead write a regex that finds all the words (ignoring anything with characters other than a-z and certain punctuation)?

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
$str="This is a string &quot; &euro; &aacute; &amp;";
$new_str = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i",'',$str);
echo $new_str;
```

i hope this may work

**DESC**:

```
& - starting with 
# - some HTML entities use the # sign 
?[a-z0-9] - followed by
;- ending with a semi-colon
i - case insensitive.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('#&[^;]+;#', '', "This is a string &quot; &euro; &aacute; &amp;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\d\s]*/', '', htmlspecialchars_decode($string));
```

Although it might remove some things you don't want removed. You may need to modify the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/&[^; ]+;/', function($matches){
    return html_entity_decode($matches[0], ENT_QUOTES) == $matches[0] ? $matches[0] : '';
}, $str);
```

This will work, but won't strip `&euro;` since that is not an entity in HTML 4.  If you have PHP 5.4 you can use the flags `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5` to have it work correctly with HTML5 entities like `&euro;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to totally remove entities (ie: not decoding them) then try this:

```
$string = 'This is a string &quot; &euro; &aacute; &amp;';

$pattern = '/&([#0-9A-Za-z]+);/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```