# Delete special char &#92;

Tags: php, string, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

How can i delete a html-special char \ from a string.

```
$string = 'This is &#92; a string with &#92; special characters &#92;';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace("char_to_rep","",$string); // replacing with nothing means deleting
```

also ref. 
[how-to-remove-html-special-chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars)

Comment: $content = str_replace('\\', '', $content);

Comment: $string = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$input);

Answer (score 0):

use `str_replace` and replace special char with an empty character

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace("#"," ",$string)
```

try this code for all special char

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for help, but is there a better way tho do this below?

```
    $post = '(&repl^eac&e_+';

    function repleace($post) {
        $array = array('.html', '.php', '±', '§', '!', '@', '€', '`', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '<', '>', '?', '/', '|', '[', ']', ':', ';', ',', '~', '.');
        $post = str_replace($array, '', $post);
        $post = str_replace(' ', '_', $post);
        $post = str_replace('-', '_', $post);
        return strtolower('/'.$post.'/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function($input) {
   $input = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$input);
   $input = ucfirst($input);
   return $input;
}
```

The php pre_repleace function within the /&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i characters works fine.