# Copied-and-pasted domain name getting &#8206; added to end

Tags: php, mysql, html

When I copy a domain name from Google Maps and then paste it into a form I built, it enters  it into a MySQL database with **`&#8206;`** appended at the end of the domain name.

Any idea how I could strip that **`&#8206;`** off of the domain name?

The relevant code is below

```
<div class="friend5title"><label for="url">Website:</label></div> 
    <div class="friend5field"><input name="website" type="text" id="website" maxlength="150"></div>



$website = mysql_real_escape_string($website);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO submission VALUES ('$website')");
```

Comment: Do you also have the example input?

Comment: have you tried trim? `trim(mysql_real_escape_string($website));` And some info about that character: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Comment: Not sure why it's happening, but that character is left-to-right mark http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a control character ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark ).

Ignore all of my previous answer I just realized (since I wrote quickly) it isn't in unicode it is actually in a HTML entity format so you need to strip that HTML entity out:

```
preg_replace('/(&#8206;)/', '', $string);
```

An alternative is to actually purify your string and purge it of all HTML entities since it shouldn't really have any in it. Normally there could be special characters like `&amp;` but these should not exist in a URL taken from an input field I reckon.

Here is a question about removing HTML entities with a solid answer: [How to remove html special chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars)

As to why it is happening: it is possible that someone has a foreign browser which artifically makes the text in inputs go a certain way but in turn by adding this html entity.

Answer (score 0):

On pasting in the input field you did copy a left-to-right character, with unicode number 8206. As the browser evidently did have a form not in some unicode character set (like UTF-8), it sent to the server that character as numeric entity `&#8206;`. The server has to decode these, or the form (and page) has to be changed to accept UTF-8.

In the case of your LTR-character, it seems superfluous. You could add an `onchange=...` to remove characters < 0 and > 127 for the URL. They still are characters, so that is easily done.