# Displaying only some content of more content

Tags: php, html

I have a content like

```
<p>
<strong><span style="font-family: monospace; white-space: pre-wrap; ">Description:Getting Started contains a list of tasks you might want to perform when you set up your computer. Tasks in Getting Started include: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  Dnescription:Getting Started contains a list of tasks you might want to perform when you set up your computer. Tasks in Getting Started include:</span></strong></p>
```

Now i want to select only 50 characters i.e only

Description:Getting Started contains a list of tasks you might want to perform when you set up your computer. Tasks in Getting Started include:

it should exclude tags and   
How to achive this????

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the tags, you could use `strip_tags($text);`.
`echo substr(str_replace("&nbsp;","",strip_tags($yourText),0,50))` would print what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in PHP as below example

```
$data = '<b>Description: </b> Getting Started contains a list of tasks you might want to perform when you set up your computer. Tasks in Getting Started include:'

// remove html tags
$data = strip_tags($data);

// remove all &nbsp;

$data = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/(.*?)\]/", "[$1]$2[/$3]", html_entity_decode($data));

OR

$data = trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',$data));

//limit characters

$data = substr($data,0,50);
```

now you can echo this data anywhere in your html

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = "<p><strong><span style=\"font-family: monospace; 
       white-space: pre-wrap;\">Description:Getting Started contains a list 
       of tasks you might want to perform when you set up your computer. Tasks 
       in Getting Started include: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
       Dnescription: Getting Started contains a list of tasks you might want 
       to perform when you set up your computer. Tasks in Getting Started 
       include:</span></strong></p>";

$tmp = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$tmp);

$final = substr(strip_tags($tmp),0,50);
```

**EDIT:**

As stated, this doesn't remove html entities. So I borrowed a regexp from [How to remove html special chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars)

Now, `$final` contains your desired output.