# How to extract only text from HTML string with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to extract only text from a php string.

This php string contains html code like  tags or   etc.

So I only need a simple text from this string.

**This is the actual string:**

```
<div class="devblog-index-content battlelog-wordpress">
<p><strong>The celebration of the Recon class in our second </strong><a href="http://blogs.battlefield.com/2014/10/bf4-class-week-recon/" target="_blank">BF4 Class Week</a><strong> continues with a sneaky stroll down memory lane. Learn more about how the Recon has changed in appearance, name and weaponry over the years&hellip;</strong></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/battlelog/prod/954660ddbe53df808c23a0ba948e7971/en_US/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bf4-history-of-recon-1.jpg?v=1412871863.37"><img alt="bf4-history-of-recon-1" class="aligncenter" src="http://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/battlelog/prod/954660ddbe53df808c23a0ba948e7971/en_US/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bf4-history-of-recon-1.jpg?v=1412871863.37" style="width:619px" /></a></p>
```

**I want to show this from the string:**

```
The celebration of the Recon class in our second BF4 Class Week continues with a sneaky stroll down memory lane. Learn more about how the Recon has changed in appearance, name and weaponry over the years…
```

Actually this text will be placed in meta description tag so I don't need any HTML in meta tag.
How can I perform this? Any ideas and thoughts about this technique ?

Comment: remove all html tags with strip_tags()

Comment: use strip_tags(), check the manual and you'll get the details on how you will use it and what it does.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You may try:

```
echo(strip_tags($your_string));
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: isn't there any way we could remove html characters

Comment: Sure. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars

Comment: <style>lots of css</style> will mess this up. along with many other tags that contain text you wouldn't want

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use Html2Text. It will do a much better job than strip_tags, especially if you want to parse complicated HTML code.

Extracting text from HTML is tricky, so your best bet is to use a library built for this purpose.

https://github.com/mtibben/html2text

Install using composer:

```
composer require html2text/html2text
```

Basic usage:

```
$html = new \Html2Text\Html2Text('Hello, &quot;<b>world</b>&quot;');

echo $html->getText();  // Hello, "WORLD"
```

Comment: Warning: this library does NOT return text from meta tags.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another option for someone else who may need this, the [Stringizer](https://github.com/jasonlam604/Stringizer) library might be an option, see [Strip Tags](https://github.com/jasonlam604/Stringizer#striptags).

Full disclosure I'm the owner of the project.

Comment: cool project, although internally uses `strip_tags()` You have any idea of making a function that deals with inline css styling?